Equivariant Vector Bundles = Isomorphisms of Pullback Bundles

Folklore: Given a $G$-action $\mu:G\times X\rightarrow X$, a $G$-equivariant vector bundle $E\xrightarrow{\pi}X$ is the same thing as an isomorphism of the pullback bundles $\psi:\text{pr}_2^*E\cong \mu^*E$.

I tried to think about this, and it's obvious that $\text{pr}_2^*E$ has fibers $(\text{pr}_2)_{(g,x)} = E_x$ and that the fiber of $\mu^*E$ over $(g,x)\in G\times X$ is $E_{g\cdot x}$. Therefore, a vector bundle isomorphism gives me a collection of linear isomorphisms $\psi_{(g,x)}:E_x\rightarrow E_{g\cdot x}$.
The fact that $X$ acts on $G$ and that that $\psi$ commutes with the two projections says that $\pi(g\cdot e) = g\cdot \pi(e)$ for all $e\in E$ and $\psi_{(h,g\cdot x)}\circ \psi_{(g,x)} = \psi_{hg, x}$ which says that the map $G\times E\rightarrow E$ is associative like an action should be.
However, I need to also show that $\text{id}_G\cdot e = e$ for all $e\in E$ to see that I actually have an action on $E$. But $\psi_{(\text{id}_G, x)}:E_x\rightarrow E_x$ could just be some random automorphism, and need not be the identity map.
Does this mean the folklore is wrong? Should it really be that an equivariant vector bundle is an isomorphism of these pullbacks with the additional proviso that $\psi_{\text{id}_G, \bullet}:$ is the identity? Or can I still squeeze the identity axiom of an action out of here somewhere?
Extra: Should this equivalence extend to a general sheaf (of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules) over X?

Your "folklore" is ill-formed since $E$ is not in scope after "same thing as".
